# Session state - strange behaviour when injecting with Autofac

Tags: c#, session, autofac

Consider I have autofac configured in mvc app like this:

```
builder.RegisterModule(new AutofacWebTypesModule());
```

It is needed to inject session state:

```
internal class DefaultSessionAccess : ISessionAccess
{
    private readonly HttpSessionStateBase session;

    public DefaultSessionAccess(HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }

    public void Put(string key, object @object)
    {
        this.session.Add(key, @object);
    }
}
```

The problem is the following code that is put in a some controller:

```
public class SomeController : Controller
{
    private ISessionAccess session;

    public SomeController(ISessionAccess session)
    {
        this.session = session;
    }


    public ActionResult SomeAction()
    {
        this.session.Put("key", "value");
        var isNull = this.HttpContext.Session["key"] == null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that on my local machine (IIS) `isNull` is **false** - object is properly saved in session. But when I deploy it to azure, **isNull is... true**! Somehow object is not saved in session.

When I put it directly:

```
 this.HttpContext.Session["key"] = "value";
```

it works fine on both servers.

According to documentation, `HttpContext.Current.Session` is registered as `HttpSessionStateBase`.

Why it happens?

Comment: Do you have a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/)?

Comment: Use `HttpContext.Current.Session` directly into your `DefaultSessionAccess`. Don't inject an `HttpSessionStateBase`. This makes your `DefaultSessionAccess` stateless and will make it much harder to cause captive dependencies.

Comment: Seems like this is more a "different behavior for session when in Azure" than "strange behavior with Autofac" question. [If you look at the code](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Mvc/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Integration.Mvc/AutofacWebTypesModule.cs) Autofac is just returning the standard MVC abstraction wrapper around the current session. No magic there. A better question title might help get the right eyes on your question.

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Session` helped, Captive Dependency? No, I do not think so, I believe my DI ocntaienr is configured propertl.